# Maximum or suggested number of bound query-parameters in InnoDB (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, innodb, parameter

We have code that adds thousands of parameters to a query as members of an IN (...) criterion. My aesthetics say to bucket it into multiple queries, but I want an objective reason.

Does InnoDB have a maximum number of parameters per query? Does it hurt performance to have over a certain number?

Comment: Version 5.1 had issues (but no limit); 5.7 has improvements (still no limit).

Answer (score 1):

With that many values you are likely to run into estimation errors during query plan generation. This will lead to it choosing worse (slower-performing) plans than it might otherwise.

With that many values I would suggest INSERTing them into an actual table, with index(es), which is JOINed to in the query. Logically the two are the same. Practically, aesthetically and performance wise it is likely to be better, even with the additional writes.

Comment: We don't need all rows inserted at once; we can bucket n rows at a time.

What is a good value for n? How many parameters can we insert efficiently in one query?

Comment: Multi-row INSERT is best done 100-1000 rows at a time.

Comment: If you are using replication, there are other considerations.

Comment: In a batch window, with no other activity, I would write several thousand rows per batch, perhaps up to 10,000 rows on larger servers. With concurrent OLTP I would start at 100 per batch and see how it goes. As always, test and monitor.